# FitNesse RowFixture: contains, startsWith, endsWith

Tags: .net, fitnesse

Is it possible to express this in a RowFixture in FitNesse for .net:

```
contains(data)
startswith(data)
endswith(data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a quick look around, I found the answer to my own question:

You can add cell handlers to add specific behavior to your tests

```
!|cell handler loader|
|load|SubstringHandler|
|load|StartsWithHandler|
|load|EndsWithHandler|
```

You can then do a test like this:

```
!|My fixture|
|Content|
|..contained..|
|starts with..|
|..ends with|
```

Comment: For those wanting more information about cell handlers Uncle Bob Martin, the developer of the original Java version of FitNesse, has a page about them:  http://butunclebob.com/FitNesse.UserGuide.DotNet.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteCellHandlerTests.SuiteOptionalAndCustomHandlerTests.TestCustomHandler