# FitNesse/Slim String Operators

Tags: .net, operators, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Is it possible to express this in a Query Table in FitNesse with SLIM for .net:

```
contains(data)
startswith(data)
endswith(data)
```

I know from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767345/fitnesse-rowfixture-contains-startswith-endswith) it was possible for FitNesse/Fit with `cell handler loader`. I'm looking for the equivalent in Slim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regular expressions with slim, check it out: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ValueComparisons

Comment: Thanks, this will solve my problem ... for now.

This should work technically. However, this will undermine the original intent of FitNesse. FitNesse is intended to be a communication platform between customer, tester and developer. Only (some) developers understand regular expressions.

=> see "Bridging the communication gap" -- Gojko Adzic

Answer (score 0):

No, the Slim test system doesn't provide a way to customize the comparison of cell contents.